# Laravel Showing Different Data From Database Data

Tags: php, laravel, authentication, laravel-5, laravel-5.3

I have been working on an app for sometime now.. all of a sudden i'm getting this weird error. The data being displayed is different from what i have in my database.
This is what i have in my database'

```
id - 1
name - Jon Doe
email - jondoe@gmail.com
status - jobseeker
created_at - 2017-06-20 21:02:47
updated_at - 2017-06-20 21:02:47
```

But when i display the data, this is what i get

```
{"id":1,"name":"Jon Doe","email":"jondoe@gmail.com","status":"employer","created_at":"2017-06-20 21:02:47","updated_at":"2017-06-20 21:02:47","employer":null}
```

**And I'm using blade "{{Auth::user()}}" to display the user info after logging in**

I think it has something to do with the "attribute" and "original" when you vardump the data.

I don't know where the changes is happening. I'm using the Laravel default authentication to create the user.

This is my create user form..

```
<form role="form" method="POST" action="{{ route('register') }}">
                  {{ csrf_field() }}

                  <div class="form-group{{ $errors->has('name') ? ' has-error' : '' }}">
                    <label>Name</label>
                    <input type="text" class="form-control" name='name' placeholder="Your Name" required>
                    @if ($errors->has('name'))
                        <span class="help-block">
                            <strong>{{ $errors->first('name') }}</strong>
                        </span>
                    @endif
                  </div>

                  <div class="form-group{{ $errors->has('email') ? ' has-error' : '' }}">
                    <label>Email</label>
                    <input type="email" class="form-control" name='email' placeholder="Your Email" required>
                    @if ($errors->has('email'))
                        <span class="help-block">
                            <strong>{{ $errors->first('email') }}</strong>
                        </span>
                    @endif
                  </div>

                  <div class="form-group{{ $errors->has('password') ? ' has-error' : '' }}">
                    <label>Password</label>
                    <input type="password" class="form-control" name="password" placeholder="Your Password" required>
                    @if ($errors->has('password'))
                        <span class="help-block">
                            <strong>{{ $errors->first('password') }}</strong>
                        </span>
                    @endif
                  </div>
                  <div class="form-group">
                    <label>Re-type Password</label>
                    <input type="password" class="form-control" name="password_confirmation" placeholder="Re-type Your Password" required>
                  </div>

                  <div class="form-group">
                    <label >Register As</label>
                    <select class="form-control" required name="status">
                      <option value="">--select--</option>
                      <option value="jobseeker">Job Seeker </option>
                      <option value="employer"> Employer </option>
                    </select>
                  </div>
                  <div class="white-space-10"></div>
                  <div class="form-group no-margin">
                    <button class="btn btn-theme btn-lg btn-t-primary btn-block">Register</button>
                  </div>
                </form>
```

This is my User Model

```
class User extends Authenticatable
{
use Notifiable;

/**
 * The attributes that are mass assignable.
 *
 * @var array
 */
protected $fillable = [
    'name', 'email', 'password','status'
];

/**
 * The attributes that should be hidden for arrays.
 *
 * @var array
 */
protected $hidden = [
    'password', 'remember_token',
];

public function employer(){
  return $this->hasOne('App\Employer');
}

public function jobseeker(){
  return $this->hasOne('App\Jobseeker','user_id');
}
}
```

This is the editing i did so that the 'status' can be added to the user table since it doesn't come with the default laravel authentication.

I edited the registerController's Create function to this

```
protected function create(array $data)
{
    return User::create([
        'name' => $data['name'],
        'email' => $data['email'],
        'status' => $data['status'],
        'password' => bcrypt($data['password']),
    ]);
}
```

And this is My user migration table

```
public function up()
{
    Schema::create('users', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->increments('id');
        $table->string('name');
        $table->string('email')->unique();
        $table->string('password');
        $table->string('status')->nullable();
        $table->rememberToken();
        $table->timestamps();
    });
}
```

Hope this helps

Comment: I know you think we, at Stackoverflow,  are magicians to tell you what's wrong without looking at any of your code, but honestly, we are just mortal humans. Kindly post relevant code where you get the data from the database and how it is being processed. Regarding the last two fields, Laravel adds them by default

Comment: sorry.. i added more information

Comment: edited again.. The data displayed is not what is in the database

Answer (score 0):

Laravel is adding Timestamps by default. Look into your create_users_table.php file in the "migrations" folder. I assume you used the

> php artisan make:auth

command so your file should look something like this:

```
public function up()
{
    Schema::create('users', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->increments('id');
        $table->string('name');
        $table->string('email')->unique();
        $table->string('password');
        $table->rememberToken();
        $table->timestamps();
    });
}
```

the

```
        $table->timestamps();
```

line is adding the "created_at" and "updated_at" fields.

Comment: could you describe your problem a little bit more?

Comment: so you are confused why the status is "employee" in your database, but "jobseeker" in your output?

Comment: when was the last time you remigrated your database?

Comment: today.. couple of hours ago

Comment: and its not possible that this is an old record? If not, I assume it has something to do with your relationships...

Comment: Its not an old record... Relationship..., I don't know.. Might be.. Can one model "HasOne" two models?